# Create SMPP server

Tags: sms, smpp

I lost 3 days trying to understand the SMPP i bought an Application from Russia but they provide OTP with protocol called SMPP ... I asked local company in my country Jordan middle East country they refused to give me SMPP account because as they said its for bigger company or hospital that spend 10 million SMS per year so I'm startup company i will spend in my expectations 10k for a month i searched a lot and found Alibaba cloud provide this service but I can't understand how to activate this service... Also my local company their prices is cheeper than Alibaba is there a method to have SMPP protocol works for that also?

Hope you understand my point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Im sure Jordan has more than one operator so I would suggest you send inquiry for SMPP connect to all of them. Also ask if they have some other protocol. There are some apps on the market which sends SMS thru mobile phone connected and some of them can receive SMPP as well. Check if Kannel app has this option.

Answer (score 0):

For reaching Jordan networks, you dont need to be directly connected to Jordan Operator. You could use A2P carrier that is connected to Jordan Operator.
Moreover some operator provide international A2P service, perhaps you should check abroad.

I dont know the Jordan law, but you can still use SIM box to send A2P SMS,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_box
Big company, like Airbnb, use this method in some countries.